# Сигнал от класса наследуемого от QSqlQueryModel об редактировании модели.

Tags: qt, c++

Итак...

1. есть таблица QTableView tableViewMain.
2. есть класс TableAmdinWidget (назовем для примера так =)), который управляет различными таблицами в приложении, в том числе и этой.
3. в объявлении этого класса  подключается класс AmdinWidgetSqlModel наследуемый от QSqlQueryModel. В котором переопределены методы
   `bool setData(const QModelIndex &index,const QVariant &value, int role);`
4. И в общем суть проблемы, при редактировании tableViewMain должны обновляться автоматически данные  других таблиц. Вызываю в конструкторе TableAmdinWidget
   `QObject::connect(model,SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(initViewRez(QTableView*)));`

Не работает

> `QObject::connect' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types`

Пояснения.

- В TableAmdinWidget есть метод который получает указатель на таблицу.
- Так же там есть слот initViewRez(QTableView*) в который мы кладем этот указатель - забирает данные из базы и выводит на таблицу.
- model - это указатель на класс AmdinWidgetSqlModel.

Вообщем, как-то всё... как решить эту проблему. И как вообще можно, если можно, что бы при обновлении модели *model*, автоматом обновлялись другие.

Answer (score 2):

- `SIGNAL` и `SLOT` должны иметь одинаковые аргументы *(`SLOT` при этом может не иметь их вообще, но не может иметь аргумент, отличный от аргумента `SIGNAL'a`).* Подробнее смотрите [**здесь.**](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html)
- Реализуйте *контроллер* для ваших моделей, который будет ловить `dataChanged` от одной модели и проецировать / изменять данные в других моделях.
- В планах дизайна приложения можете не переходить от идеологии `Model / View`, используемой в `Qt`, а просто создать вспомогательный класс типа `AggregatedModel`, который и будет заниматься проецированием изменений.

Comment: Думал над этим.
сделал 

private slots:
    void initUpdate();

void TableAmdinWidget::initUpdate()
{

}

результат тот же..

Comment: Можно по подробней. 
Смысл в том что у меня 1 модель наследуемая от QSqlQueryModel. все остальные чистые QSqlQueryModel которые соединяются с QTableView (и они не редактируемые.)
что самое интересное, что в старой версии программы где QSqlTableModel - редактируемая связывалась с QTableView . через тот же сигнал и похожий слот. все работало..

Answer (score 0):

Все легче, чем писали в комментарии.

1. TableAmdinWidget должен наследоваться от QObject

**.h**

> class TableAmdinWidget : public QObject {
>
> ```
> Q_OBJECT
> ```
>
> public:
>     TableAmdinWidget(QObject *parent=0);

**.cpp**

> TableAmdinWidget::TableAmdinWidget(QObject *parent)
>                     : QObject(parent) 
> { 
>     model= new  AmdinWidgetSqlModel;
>     QObject::connect(model,SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(initUpdate()));
> }

1. Так же в AmdinWidgetSqlModel
    в переопределенным

> bool setData(const QModelIndex &index,
> const QVariant &value, int role);

явно вызываем сигнал dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex).

> emit dataChanged(index,index)

P.S.
Прошу прощение модераторов, что код в цитаты оформил. ну не получается его в код)